# NGINX log_format Directive Not Working When Configuration Split into Multiple Files

Tags: nginx, logging, configuration, nginx-config, nginx-location

I've been trying to break my NGINX configuration into multiple files for easier management and maintainability. However, after splitting the files, my custom log_format directive doesn't seem to work. Here's how I organized my configuration files:

**events.conf**

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
```

**http_common.conf**

```
log_format my_custom_format 'Log: $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

**nginx-custom.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log my_custom_format;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
include events.conf;

http {
    include http_common.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**start-nginx.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting NGINX"
nginx -t
exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
        - "8082:80"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use the official NGINX image as the base
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy our custom HTML file to the NGINX HTML directory
COPY ./files/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
COPY ./files/events.conf /etc/nginx/events.conf
COPY ./files/http_common.conf /etc/nginx/http_common.conf
COPY ./files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./files/nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-custom.conf


# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy the shell script
COPY ./files/start-nginx.sh /start-nginx.sh

# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /start-nginx.sh

# Start NGINX using the script
CMD ["/start-nginx.sh"]
```

---

**Command to run**

```
docker-compose -f nginx/docker-compose.yaml down; docker-compose -f nginx/docker-compose.yaml up --build
```

After setting this up, the my_custom_format log format isn't recognized. It still shows the default logging format not the one I mentioned. How can I mention the log_format globally and mak it work inside the conf.d configurations? I don't want to have a fat configuration file in the nginx.conf